# Show trail of moving pixel in C# WinForm project

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a personal project linked to the ant colony problem.
I successfully developed everything for a console project and now I want to transpose the code in a more graphic layout with windows forms.

Using the code below the form shows correctly one moving pixel, but I'm not able to find a way to show the left trail of the movement. I tried to remove the  pictureBox1.Invalidate(), but this brings me to a static pixel in the starting point.

I would like not to reparse the map matrix and draw the pheromone trail, but only leave the drawn positions as if I'm drawing something with a pen on a piece of paper.

```
    public void RenderAnts(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        foreach (Ant a in ants)
        {
            Brush c;
            c = Brushes.DarkBlue;
            if (a.role == AntRole.Scout)
            {
                a.Move(i);
                c = Brushes.Red;
            }
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(c, a.position.x, a.position.y, 1, 1);
        }
        pictureBox1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Use RectangleF instead of Rectangle.  The last two parameters (1,1) are the width and height which are floating point numbers.  Make smaller so you don't over write old points.

Comment: Create a bitmap and draw onto that instead of directly into the picturebox during a paint event. The Paint procedure doesn't keep pixels around through invalidation cycles.

Comment: Do not call pictureBox1.Invalidate() from the Paint event or an event that is called form the Paint event ! So after removing the Invalidate and the Show you should see all your ants, provided their positions are actually correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `List<Point>` form field, where `Point` is type of ant `Position` field. On each `Move` add current ants positions to this list. I emulate moving by mouse click on `PictureBox`. Paint event handler just draws positions.

See sample

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1 = new PictureBox { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        ants.Add(new Ant { Role = AntRole.Scout, Position = new Point(50, 50) });
        ants.Add(new Ant { Role = AntRole.Scout, Position = new Point(150, 150) });
        ants.Add(new Ant { Role = AntRole.Scout, Position = new Point(100, 100) });

        pictureBox1.Paint += RenderAnts;

        pictureBox1.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                foreach (Ant a in ants)
                {
                    if (a.Role == AntRole.Scout)
                    {
                        a.Move();
                        antTrails.Add(a.Position);
                    }
                }
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        };
    }
    PictureBox pictureBox1;
    List<Ant> ants = new List<Ant>();
    List<Point> antTrails = new List<Point>();

    public void RenderAnts(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var point in antTrails)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, point.X, point.Y, 1, 1);
    }
}

public class Ant
{
    public AntRole Role;
    public Point Position;
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public void Move()
    {
        int r = rnd.Next(4);
        if (r == 0)
            Position.X--;
        else if (r == 1)
            Position.X++;
        else if (r == 2)
            Position.Y--;
        else
            Position.Y++;
    }
}

public enum AntRole
{
    Normal,
    Scout
}
```

Run and try clicking the mouse.

Comment: If I have applied correctly your hypothesis of solution, it draws trails, but all at once. Is it the same for you?
The behaviour I'm looking for is a redrawing every single step.

Comment: @sipronunciaaigor - In the `Click` event I applied a `for` loop to illustrate one hundred trails. Remove this loop.

Comment: ok, I see how it works and now I have been able to run it properly. Is there some sort of universal handler to avoid the click, or the mouse movement? I was thinking to something that simply looped until exit condition with a Thread.Sleep(amount) to slow down the simulation

Comment: Ok, given the timer, may I ask you for another handler?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that combines drawing the trail into a bitmap and the new ants onto the surface:

Prepare the bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Now the modified paint event:

```
void RenderAnts(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //pictureBox1.Invalidate();   // don't do this here!

    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    foreach (ant a in ants)
    {
        c = Brushes.DarkBlue;
        if (a.role == AntRole.Scout)
        {
            a.Move(i);
            c = Brushes.Red;
        }
        // this draws onto the surface:
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(c, a.position.x, a.position.y, 1, 1);
        // and this into the Image bitmap below:
        G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, a.position.x, a.position.y, 1, 1);
    }

}
```

Note that the surface sit **above** the Image.

I'm not sure about the details of your code; espcially the varaible `i` is unclear.. And you indeed may want to consider floats for the positions..

Do not call `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` from the `Paint` event as this usually will trigger the `Paint` event again.. Instead this should probably move to the animation timer tick or a button click etc..

Also note the `using` clause that makes sure the `Graphics` object I create is disposed.

The example assumes that you can already draw the ants themselves correctly and simply adds the trails..

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't able to make it run and I started focusing on @alexander reply.
The "i" is a typo from the complete source code.

Comment: After making alexander's code work fine I'm after your code but it shows up the first iteration and I don't understand how to make it properly run. Sorry, but this is my first experience with graphics in winforms

Comment: Do you run the 1st two lines once? And how do you trigger the RenderAnts? From a Timer.Tick?

Comment: They run once, but I'm not triggering anything. I thought that the "Application.Run(new ShowAnts());" would have looped the main method all the time during the form lifetime.

Comment: Um, no. Nothing is happening during idle time. If you don't do anything, how do your ants move??? The normal way is to have a Timer with a Tick event that contains an `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`.. The Timer can have an Interval of maybe 200ms which would triggger the Tick 5 times per second..

Comment: I can show you how to write such an animation but you should update the question. If Move(i) is a typo, please correct it..!

Comment: As requested, I asked a new question trying to be more exaustive from the code point of view [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044137/dynamic-drawing-ants-in-winforms-during-execution-of-ant-colony).